# Windows not Activated

Tags: windows-8

I bought a laptop with Windows 8 pre-installed with a product key.

However, for sometime I get the issue that **windows are not activated** although a product key is inserted.

It also not allowing me insert the same product key again.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Please do not write in all caps and what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can contact Microsoft Answer Tech online, they will definitely help you about this.
2. Use activation by phone method, for this you will need toll or toll free Microsoft number for your country, which you can find online.
3. Try updating Windows & have scan for viruses & malware, sometimes registry settings are disturbed by malware etcetera.
4. Try booting in safe mode and scan for malware etcetera.
5. If you have installation disk have a clean install and then update and activate your PC.
6. Try this
   http://windows.microsoft.com/en-IN/windows-8/activation-errors
7. Try repairing registry settings 
   https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/968003